# Why does my site fail after restoring the database?

Tags: 7, database, backups

I tried migrating my Drupal live site to localhost to test it there. I followed the instructions in [Migrating a site](https://www.drupal.org/node/776864).

- Cleared the cache
- Disabled clean URLs
- Enabled mod_rewrite

Then I backuped my live site database. On my localhost, I created a database with the same name as my live site and ran a clean install of Drupal 7.25. Everything worked. I installed the *Backup and migrate* module, and tried to download the database; after submitting the form, the local site simply became blank and I could not access it.

I checked the local database and found that the backup database was properly copied into it. So, probably, the issue is not with the database access permissions on localhost.

I cannot figure out what causes the local site to fail.

What are the possible reasons for such a failure?

Comment: what does it say in your php error log?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of mistake. I accidentally put Entity module into the core and it generated WSOD when I tried to restore the database on my localhost. You should never put contributed modules into core modules folder.